# A generalization of Hensel lemma

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

Let A be a noetherian ring, let I be a proper
ideal of A. Suppose that A is complete and separate for the I-adic topology. Let
F(X) ∈ A[X] be a polynomial such that there exists a ∈ A with F(a) ∈ I and
(F'(a), I) = A. I want to show that
there exists an actual root α ∈ A of F which moreover coincides with a mod I.
I think this generalizes the classical Hensel Lemma over the ring of p-adic integers Zp

Answer (score 1):

You can see such a result as Theorem 10.5 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf). Replace $(F'(a),I) = A$ with $F'(a) \in A^\times$, which in practice may be equivalent.